# Trying to understand meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

```
<head>
  <title>bubblePop</title>
</head>

<body>


  <center>{{> hello}}<center>
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Bubble Pop!!!!</h1>
  {{greeting}}

</template>
```

I understand whats going on with the handlebars {{> hello}} its basically so you can insert the {{> hello}} anywhere and it will be the same thing as in the template. But I'm trying to use javascript to make a large table on my meteor app. How do I put my code in handlebars? Can I use `<template>` in my JS file? Just a bit confused heres the rest of my code:
JS:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function (){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var el;
    for(var i=1; i<=64; i++){
        el = document.createElement('div');
        $(el).addClass('button');
        $(el).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('removed');
        });
        $('#container').append(el);
    }
});


  })
<template name="bubbles">


  </template>
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    }


  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 440px;
    max-width: 440px;
}
#container > .button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    transition: all 0.07s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.07s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.07s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#container > .button:hover {
    opacity: 1;    
}
#container > .button.removed {
    background-image: none;
}
```

How can I get all of these buttons to appear? There is something I just dont get

Comment: Have you read this yet? http://www.discovermeteor.com/

Comment: I'm reading it I just have no idea what Im doing.

Comment: Chapter 3 - Templates explains pretty well what you're asking.

Comment: @cuberto I've read this chapter since this afternoon apparently I can't figure this out pretty much giving up on meteor I have no idea whats going on no matter how many times i read it and handlebar tutorials there is no way i can figure this out. I can figure out rails I can figure out every other programming language but this is so alien to me

Comment: Think of it like this - don't worry about creating elements and appending them to other elements. Your templates define HTML structures with variables wrapped in `{{ }}`. Meteor will render your templates and fill those variables in at runtime. I highly recommend looking at one of the examples. Run `meteor create --example leaderboard`. Look at the HTML and JS files - they're fairly short and seem pretty easy to grok.

Comment: In other words, the HTML defines the structure of your app, while the JS defines the behavior. You say you understand rails. In meteor, the HTML is your view, and the JS is your controller and model.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to apply imperative programming techniques to a reactive paradigm.

When data changes, templates are implicitly re-rendered with the updated data.

Try to create a simple loop in handlebars and bind the table to a collection. Then you control the number of rows or order of the rows via the collection (or cursor).

Remember, if you bind the template to a document, `this` in the template is the document. So, you can show/hide buttons based on methods or members. Eg. `{{getFirstName}}` is like saying `my_document.getFirstName()`.

```
<table id="comments">
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
    </tr>
    {{#each comments}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{one}}</td>
            <td>{{two}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Ah its alright. I have no idea what is being told here. Meteor is way too confusing for me to try I suppose thanks for the answer.

Comment: Everything's confusing when you first start to use it. Stick with it. Meteor is a game changer. There will be lots of work in this framework for years to come. It's also a real pleasure to use when you get used to it. It could be that my explanation just isn't that good. :-)